# Conditional validation if user selects yes

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, conditional-statements

I have a jQuery validation script using `jquery.validate.js`

What I need is when the user selects Yes - need additional info (required field), if user selects No - fine, proceed

Tried for a long time to get this working without success - added

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Here's my PHP code:

```
// If form type is radio, display as a radio button with yes/no answers
            if ($form_type == 'radio')
            {
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"screen_184\"  value=\"Yes\" checked /> <label>Yes</label> <input type=\"radio\" name=\"screen_184\"  value=\"No\" /> <label>No</label><br /><br />"; 

                // If from type is radio and additional information is required, display a textarea 
                if ($extra_info == 'Yes')
                {
                                   if ($row['required'] == 'Yes') {$class = 'required';} else {$class = 'input_field';}
                echo "<textarea class=\"$class\" maxlegth=\"500\" name=\"screentext_184\" /></textarea></li><br /><br />\n";
            }
```

Comment: Where is the jQuery code in this? What did you try in jQuery?

Comment: you may want to look at adding the required class to the textarea with javascript instead of trying to do it server side.  Or a better solution ma ybe a custom validator for jquery.validation

Comment: For a question about server-side code, you need to show the _rendered_ HTML **along with** the jQuery/JavaScript.  Your PHP has absolutely nothing to do with this jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 2):

When you ask a question about jQuery, you need to show your jQuery code, not your PHP.

However, within the jQuery Valdiate plugin, to make `required` conditional for one field based  upon the state of another `input`, use [`depends`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) as follows...

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            "screentext_184": {
                required: {
                    depends: function(element) {
                        return $("input[name='screen_184'][value='Yes']").is(":checked");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform"> 
    Yes: <input type="radio" name="screen_184" value="Yes" />
    No: <input type="radio" name="screen_184" value="No" checked="checked" />
    <textarea name="screentext_184"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/qjhv6/**

For the demo, the `text` `input` field is optional until the "yes" `radio` is ticked.

---

**EDIT**:  As per comment by Ryley, this can be simplified even further:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            "screentext_184": {
                required: "input[name='screen_184'][value='Yes']:checked"
            }
        }  
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/txryf/

Comment: You can go even simpler - `required:"input[name='field2'][value='yes']:checked"` - http://jsfiddle.net/jGfC5/1/

Comment: @Ryley, wow, thank-you, I did not know that.  What's the point of `depends` if we can do that simply with `required`?

Comment: If you need a function!  i.e. to check a JS variable or anything that you can't manage to fit in a selector

Comment: @Ryley, makes sense.  Ok, now I see how the value of the selector replaces `true` or `false`.  And all this time I thought you could only specify `true` or `false` (and `depends: {...}`) as values for `required`.  Ironically, the only example of `depends` in the documentation uses this very same "superfluous" case.

Comment: Thanks for your replies - please advise how I need to implement this. Do I need to edit the js file with the code above?

Comment: @user2043910, I already showed you two examples about how to implement this.  Otherwise, you'll need to show your relevant HTML and jQuery code.  (PHP has nothing to do with this.)

Comment: @user2043910, I've updated the field names in my demo code to match your actual code.  I cannot customize this any further without seeing your rendered HTML and jQuery.